# kendodropdownlist filter json response that has field

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, kendo-ui

I am doing the below currently; all my JSON entries have `styleName`, however some have the field `txt`, I want to display only the `styleName` data that has the `txt` field in my dropdown list.

```
var dataSourceJSON = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: dataURL,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET'
        }
    }});dataSourceJSON.read();

    $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource    : dataSourceJSON,
        dataTextField : "styleName"
    });
```

Before using kendo, I was achieving this with the below, within a `fetch` on classic  dropdowns. But I am unsure how to incorporate such logic with `kendoDropDownList`

```
if (data[i].txt) {
     option.text = data[i].styleName;
     dropdown.add(option);
}..../
```

**Update**, this is where I am currently at; I can `console.log` the correct data in my schema parse but am still having a hard time getting the filtered data into the dropdown.

```
  var ctemp;
  var dataSourceJSON = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: dataURL,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET'
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function(datC) {
            console.log(datC);
            for (let i = 0; i < datC.length; i++) {
                if (datC[i].txt) {
                    ctemp = datC; // <-- This works and what I need
                    console.log(ctemp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    });dataSourceJSON.read();

    $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Choose",
        dataSource    : dataSourceC,
        dataTextField : ctemp // <--- does nothing
    });
```

Comment: Use [schema.parse](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemaparse)

Comment: Hey @GaloisGirl thank you! I've managed to successfully filter it with schema parse, but for some reason am still having a hard time getting the filtered data into the dropdown. anything else I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use kendo `dataSource` filter for this case. [DataSource filter](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter)

Just check if a field is notnull and that's it.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { styleName: "Style 1", txt: 'test' },
    { styleName: "Style 2" },
    { styleName: "Style 3", txt: 'test' },
  ],
  filter: { field: "txt", operator: "isnotnull" }
});
```

I made an example: [Filter by field](https://dojo.telerik.com/IhasICiz)

Comment: Yup. Thats exactly what I ended up doing!

Comment: I actually used this one; not sure which is better or if it would matter done the line: '                { field: "txt", operator: "neq", value: null}'